# i am not able to create a collection in ravendb, if i do not have any document in it

Tags: database, c#-4.0, collections, nosql, ravendb

I have created a document in ravendb. Using session.advanced.getmetadata(see in code) , i gave a name to Raven-Entity-Name in metadata, after that i deleted that document in same function.Then i saw collection is also removed.If i delete the document manually from raven studio then the collection remains in the database.How a collection persist even if there is no document from code part? thanks in advance !!

My c# code is :

```
public CreateCollectionResult CreateCollection(string databaseName, string collectionName)
    {
        CreateCollectionResult createCollectionResult = new CreateCollectionResult();

        Collection collection1234 = new Collection();
        try
        {
            using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession(databaseName))
            {
                Guid guid = new Guid("12345678-1111-1111-2222-000000000000");
                session.Store(collection1234, guid, "april-Days/10");
                session.Advanced.GetMetadataFor<Collection>(collection1234)[Constants.RavenEntityName] = collectionName;
                //session.Delete<Collection>(collection1234);
                session.SaveChanges();
                createCollectionResult.IsOperationSuccessfull = true;
            }
        }
        //exception if database not found
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            createCollectionResult.IsOperationSuccessfull = false;
            createCollectionResult.Error = ex;
        }
        return createCollectionResult;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In RavenDB, collections are virtual, they are only there as long as you have at least one doc in that document.